# Can someone tell me why this conditional formatting is wrong? Date ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm just literally doing a 3-color scale like so:

```
Minimum: =($L$3-TODAY())<7

Midpoint: =($L$3-TODAY())<14

Max: =($L$3-TODAY())>14
```

I thought this would be correct but it won't format anything :|

I'm trying to do three things:

- `RED` if `TODAY()` or 7 days before
- `YELLOW` if `TODAY()` between 7 &14
- `GREEN` everything else so `TODAY()>14`

Can anyone see anything wrong with that? I don't understand why it isn't correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved it myself:

**Minimum:** Less than `NOW()`

**Midpoint:** Between `NOW()` and `NOW()+7`

**Max:** Greater than `NOW()+7`